# what is the type of the return value of binary operators in C

Tags: expression, operator-keyword, return-type

can anyone tell me the type of value to which e.g. a==b (or in general any if-statement) evaluates in C? Probably char or int?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't test it on your own to find out?

Comment: If you show me a way to determine a variable's type in C(99) ... (typeof doesn't do it, obviously)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C language, result of Boolean/relational expression is non-zero (true) or zero (false), which is a signed int type.

Comment: Thank you - can you give any reference, like man pages or the C Reference?